# How to store the character ú in char array with std::cin?

Tags: c++, arrays, character-encoding, char, cin

In console the user type several characters including: ú .I would like store these characters in a char array using std::cin, but the character ú is stored as: 163'£', I really want to store it as: 163'ú', How could I do it?.

Comment: How characters above the standard ASCII (up to `127` decimal) are presented depends on your locale and language settings. I really recommend you start using a standard encoding like UTF-8 to represent your characters. Read more on [UTF-8 Everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/)

Comment: Did you try to output your character to ```cout```?

Comment: yes, I send to cout ú and prints it, but the user type ú and cin don´t store the character.

Answer (score 2):

The character set of the console  defines how a char value will be displayed. For example:

- if console uses [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) or [windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) character set, the value `163` is a `£`;
- if console uses an old [DOS code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), the same value of 163 is an `ù`.

In principle, if you input a char from the console and output this char on the same console, you should graphically get the same result.

However, if there's some mixing, this is not the case.  For example if you input `ù` on a CMD window using 850 code page, but then output the result in a unicode window, you would get `£` as output.  Same phenomenon if you write a file to the disk and open it in an editor using another character encoding.

Unfortunately, console settings and default encodings are things which are very much system dependent, and more information is needed to provide you accurate advise on the best way to solve the issue.